# C pointers nested

Tags: pointers

I can't understand code from CCS C compiler. The code is:

```
addr[0] =  *(((char*)&block_number)+2);
```

I guess that "`&block_number`" is address of variable named "block_number". After that I get lost.

Answer (score 1):

Let's split this up:

```
*(ptr+2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
ptr[2]
```

Here, `ptr` is a `char*` pointing to the address of `block_number`.

So say `block_number` is an instance of a struct like this:

```
struct {
  char a;
  char b;
  char c;
  char d;
} block_number
```

Then `addr[0]` will contain the value of `c` (assuming the values are packed with no space between them). This is because the pointer to `block_number` is converted to a `char*`, and then indexed like an array.

So basically, this reads the third byte in `block_number`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to say when one do not know what block_number is. Let say it is a integer with the value `0xdeadbeef`:

```
unsigned int block_number = 0xdeadbeef;
```

on a little endian architecture (i.e. x86):

```
*(char *)&block_number is 0xef, 
*(((char *)&block_number) + 1) is 0xbe and
*(((char *)&block_number) + 2) is 0xad.
```

While if block_number is a `char` then `*(((char *)&block_number) + 2)` could point to a adjacent variable, let say block_number is declared on the stack:

```
char a = 0xab, b = 0xbc, block_size = 0xcd, c = 0xde, d = 0xef;
```

Then `((char *)&block_size + 2` could point to i.e. `a` and `*(((char *)&block_size + 2)` would return `0xab`. Because the stack is most commonly ordered from max address to lower addresses:

```
heap                                              stack
[... ->     <- d    | c    | block_size | b    | a    ]
[... ->     <- 0xef | 0xde | 0xcd       | 0xbc | 0xab ]
```

But this is never certain as C does not put any constraints on the compiler where to locate `a` and the location is probably undefined.

For `sizeof(char)` it is **always** `1`. `char` is one character, that is why you do not need to specify length*sizeof(char) to malloc if you want to allocate memory. You only do:

```
int length = 20;
void *mem = malloc(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. &block_number is the address of that variable and it is cast to  a char and a 2 added to the value. For example if &block_number is 0x0000, then addr[0] after executing the line will contain 0x0002 if the sizeof(char) on the platform is 2, or whatever the size is.

Comment: Or it might be 0x0004 if sizeof(char) is 2

Comment: @AdrianGrigo: it can't be, by definition.

Comment: The question has changed since I first answered it. Now it is placing the value of block_number[2] at addr[0], whereas it originally was placing the address (it didn't make sense, but that was the code).

Answer (score 0):

1. `&block_number` is the address of the object `block_number`.
2. `(char*)&block_number` treats that address as the address of the first element in an array of bytes. Let's call this pointer `p`, and it is a pointer-to-`char`.
3. `*(((char*)&block_number)+2)` is thus `*(p + 2)`, which is identical to `p[2]`, i.e. it denotes the third element of the array.

In other words, you are obtaining the third byte of the binary representation of the object `block_number` (and storing it it `addr[0]`).